# PDO Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: php, mysql

I know this has to be a simple fix and I partially understand why I am getting this error but don't know how to fix it. I've looked over the docs but can't find a solution other than using buffered queries option. I have tried that as well but it doesn't work.

The error is: PDO Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

The error is coming from the line where I am building the $result array.

```
foreach($phones as $phone)
{
    $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare("CALL phones(:phone)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result[] = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT @phone;")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using an OUT parameter?

Comment: Yes, because out params are only for outputting a single row. In my case, I need multiple rows.

Comment: You can "return" result sets from a procedure.

Comment: Hmm.. Would you have a link for that by chance? I read yesterday on MySQL's site that out params will only output a single row. Unless, of course, I'm talking about something entirely different. Would you have a procedure handy to show that would do this? Thanks.

Comment: yeah...it's not an out parameter in this case. See my "answer". Not exactly what you've asked for  ...but maybe what you want =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's take an example table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id int auto_increment,  
  phone int,  
  primary key(id),  
  unique key(phone)  
)
```

an example procedure

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE phones(in p INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT phone FROM foo WHERE phone > p;
END//
delimiter ;
```

and some sample data

```
INSERT INTO foo (phone) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

Using PDOStatement it is possible to fetch the result set from the stored procedure.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL phones(:phone)");
$stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$phone = 1;
$stmt->execute();
do {
  echo "\nresult set: ";
  while($row=$stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['phone'], " | ";
  }
} while($stmt->nextRowset());
```

prints `result set: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |`

(test environment: php 5.3.1/winxp, mysql 5.1.37)

The `do { } while($stmt->nextRowset());` loop probably solves your "original" problem as well.

Comment: Even down to the test environment. :)  What a guy. Thanks for the effort Volker. Whatever I'm doing is definitely flawed. I tried your example and it works. It is exactly what I need so what I need to do is compare my code with yours to see where I'm going wrong. My feeling is that my problem is in my procedure, and not necessarily the PHP. Thanks a bunch for your effort, it really helped me!

Comment: If the problem is still the "other unbuffered queries are active" error try `while($stmt->nextRowset()) {}` right after `$stmt->execute()`. It should clear/empty/release any "active" result set.

Comment: I tried running the same 'do-while' statement paired with my code but I get an error on my XAMPP machine saying this feature is not available. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JM4 - Please post the exact (complete) message you get along with the php version+os you're using as a new question.

Comment: @VolkerK - just a couple years late seeing this. Ha. I can't even remember what the issue was here but it does seem that new queries cannot be executed in result loop from a stored procedure (use buffered query doesn't help). Wish I didn't have to fetchAll the results